# why sublime text3 and windows7 notepad have difference in displaying the same *.txt file?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, notepad

in sublime text3,it displays like this:
    **

```
    We are not what we should be  
    We are not what we need to be  
    But at least we are not what we used to be  
       -- Football Coach
```

**

in win7 notepad,it displays like this:

```
We are not what we should beWe are not what we need to beBut at least we are not what we used to be  -- Football Coach
```

i'm learning google python class recently, this is one of the exercises.I know maybe what the sublime displays means the orignal idea.But how can we get just one line text in notepad? so confusing.

Comment: Notepad specifically only recognizes the line break `CR, LF (0x0d, 0x0a)`, copy paste it into word/wordpad to convert the line breaks to that format. (Sublime Text recognizes other forms of line breaks such as individual carriage returns or line feeds.)

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text is a cross platform text editor. But Microsoft's notepad is not.

So, notepad understands CRLF (`\r\n`) as line-breaks. LF (`\n`) is not identified as line-break.

But sublime text, being a cross platform text editor, identifies CRLF and LF as line-breaks.

CRLF: Carriage return + line feed, Unicode characters 000D + 000A.

LF: Line feed, Unicode character 000A.